# Paging with LINQ without sorting

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I want to create paging with LINQ to entity (EF) ,I found `Skip` method but it is only supported for sorted input,so I think it will be slow in large amount of rows. Is any way to paging without sorting it first?

Comment: `Skip` can be used with any `IEnumerable<T>`. Are you using some kind of ORM that translates the Linq query to SQL?

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes I forgot to add it to tags

Comment: If you have a PK, sort on that. Usually the underlying RDBMS can do this efficiently.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to sort it :( If use `Skip` method in EF without `OrderBy` you will get next exception: `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A database is not obliged to return the set of records in same order, for a specific SQL query, without a specific order declared.

You may run the same query and first 10 records be different on each run. Database will execute this based on what is best for itself (what part of data is cached in memory, what parts changed before two executions of the same query and the like).

So regardless of what ORM you use, you have to specify in what order you want the data. And be sure you have a properly defined index for the field that you are ordering the records based on that.

Comment: now that I should sort first, I worry about performance of this : `context.Users.Where(u => u.Id != currentUserId).Select(u => u).OrderBy(u=>u.Id).Skip((page-1)*perPage).Take(perPage);`

Comment: I think `.Select(u => u)` is not needed here; and yes; this is essentially what should be done to get what you want. Since it's `Id` I guess it's you primary key, so I think your performance should not be so bad.